# Can't get this form to work on HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, window.open

sorry for what might be a noob question.. I've been fiddling with this form for some time now but I can't seem to make it work for some reason. The colour changes work but the submit button simply does not lead to the link..

```
<center>
    <form name="form1" method="POST">
        <input id="codebox1" type="text" onchange="checkFilled1();" />
        <input id="codebox2" type="text" onchange="checkFilled2();" />
        <input id="codebox3" type="text" onchange="checkFilled3();" />
        <br>
        <br>
        <input id="button1" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="testResults(this.form)" />
    </form>
</center>
```

And here are the functions:

```
<script>
function checkFilled1() {
    var inputVal = document.getElementById("codebox1");
    if (inputVal.value == "1234") {
        inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
    } else {
        inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
checkFilled1();
</script>

<script>
function checkFilled2() {
    var inputVal = document.getElementById("codebox2");
    if (inputVal.value == "1234") {
        inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
    } else {
        inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}

checkFilled2();
</script>

<script>
function checkFilled3() {
    var inputVal = document.getElementById("codebox3");
    if (inputVal.value == "1234") {
        inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
    } else {
        inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}

checkFilled3();
</script>

<script>
function testResults() {
    var inputVal1 = document.getElementById("codebox1");
    var inputVal2 = document.getElementById("codebox2");
    var inputVal3 = document.getElementById("codebox3");
    if (inputVal1.value == "1234") && (inputVal2.value == "1234") && (inputVal3.value == "1234") {
        window.open("http://google.com", "_parent");
    } else {

    }
}

testResults();
</script>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Get rid of the inline Javascript and move it all into its own file. All the inline calls to a function can be done by simply adding an id to the item and referencing it in you Javascript file.

Comment: @MichaelMcCoy can you elaborate what you said about inline function calls? Any tutorial or MDN docs would be nicer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
<form name="form1" method="POST">

[...]

<input id="button1" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="testResults(this.form)" />
```

to this:

```
<form name="form1" onSubmit="testResults()" method="POST">

[...]

<input id="button1" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

## ===

***Refactored Version***

```js
var codeboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('codebox');

function testResults() {

    var correctValues = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < codeboxes.length; i++) {
        if (codeboxes[i].value === '1234') {
            correctValues++;
        }
    }

    if (correctValues === codeboxes.length) {
     window.alert('You have entered all ' + codeboxes.length + ' values correctly.');
    }

    else {
 window.alert('You have not entered all ' + codeboxes.length + ' values correctly.');
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" onSubmit="testResults()" method="POST">
<input class="codebox" type="text" />
<input class="codebox" type="text" />
<input class="codebox" type="text" />
<input id="button1" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Rounin! But it still doesn't work.. This error comes up instead of the form: 
 
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. 
The document tree is shown below. 

<Error>
<Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
<Message>Invalid argument.</Message>
<Details>POST object expects Content-Type multipart/form-data</Details>
</Error>

Comment: More out of curiosity than anything else, I have added my own "refactored version" to the post above. As far as I can tell, it's working fine.

Comment: Thanks, Rounin! All of your suggestions made it work offline. Must be a problem with the specific template (HTML5) I tried to include this into..

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the method, testResults which does not accept any parameters. Change the submit button markup to the following and the testResults method will be invoked.

```
<input id="button1" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="testResults()" />
```

No parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your JavaScript. Open up your browser tools console and see:

> Unexpected token &&

You need to wrap the whole if condition in parentheses, like this:

```
if ((inputVal1.value == "1234") && (inputVal2.value == "1234") && (inputVal3.value == "1234")) {
window.open("http://www.example.com", "_parent");
```

That said, this won't *submit* the data in the form. It will just open the give URL if the conditions are true — which is what you asked in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkFilled(inp) {
  var inputVal = inp;
  if (inputVal.value == "1234") {
    inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
  } else {
    inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}

function testResults() {
  var inputVal1 = document.getElementById("codebox1");
  var inputVal2 = document.getElementById("codebox2");
  var inputVal3 = document.getElementById("codebox3");
  if ((inputVal1.value == "1234") && (inputVal2.value == "1234") && (inputVal3.value == "1234")) {
    alert('Here comes window opening...');
    //window.open("http://google.com", "_blank");
  } else {
    alert('Error ...');
  }
}

//testResults();
```

```html
<form name="form1" method="POST">
  <input id="codebox1" type="text" onchange="checkFilled(this);" />
  <input id="codebox2" type="text" onchange="checkFilled(this);" />
  <input id="codebox3" type="text" onchange="checkFilled(this);" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <input id="button1" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="testResults(this.form)" />
</form>
```

you've done one mistake at testResults() function, missing () at if ... see the snippet (with a little optimalization)

Comment: Thanks for your input! Still nothing, though. I get this error:

    This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
      <Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Invalid argument.</Message><Details>POST object expects Content-Type multipart/form-data</Details></Error>

Comment: @Lukasj10 : 
1. do you need to POST your data? If not, do write out your submit button to regular button, and don't write any method to form open tag.
2. have your html file the correct extension / and correct header (liket: <!DOCTYPE html>)?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your form tag as below,

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" onSubmit="testResults()">
```

Edit your submit button as below,

```
<input id="button1" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Edit the if statement as follow,

```
if((inputVal1.value == "1234") && (inputVal2.value == "1234") && (inputVal3.value == "1234"))
{
     window.open("http://www.google.com", "_parent");
}
```